# How can I use the theme argument in the function vitae::modern_cv()

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm updating my CV with the modern CV template of the vitae package and it's going pretty well.

According to the description I can use different themes within this template (https://pkg.mitchelloharawild.com/vitae/reference/cv_formats.html).

```
moderncv(..., theme = c("casual", "classic", "oldstyle", "banking", "fancy"))
```

However, I don't know how to incoperate this in the R Markdown header.
I have tried using brackets like `vitae::moderncv(theme = "casual")`  but I get this error: `Error: YAML output format must evaluate to a function Execution halted`

I don't know how LaTeX / YAML works..

Here's an example:

````
---
name: Marie
surname: Curie
position: "Professor"
address: "School of Physics & Chemistry, École Normale Supérieure"
phone: +1 22 3333 4444
www: mariecurie.com
email: "Marie.Curie@ens.fr"
twitter: mariecurie
github: mariecurie
linkedin: mariecurie
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"
output: vitae::moderncv
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
library(vitae)
```

# Some stuff about me

 * I poisoned myself doing research.
 * I was the first woman to win a Nobel prize
 * I was the first person and only woman to win a Nobel prize in two different sciences.

# Education

```{r}
library(tibble)
tribble(
  ~ Degree, ~ Year, ~ Institution, ~ Where,
  "Informal studies", "1889-91", "Flying University", "Warsaw, Poland",
  "Master of Physics", "1893", "Sorbonne Université", "Paris, France",
  "Master of Mathematics", "1894", "Sorbonne Université", "Paris, France"
) %>% 
  detailed_entries(Degree, Year, Institution, Where)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the theme in the YAML header like so:

```
output: 
  vitae::moderncv:
    theme: fancy
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know those spaces actually mattered :)